# RedMine + gem_dependency.rb:119:Warning: Gem::Dependency#version_requirements is deprecated and will be removed on or after August 2010

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, redmine-plugins

/redmine$ ruby script/server -e production
    => Booting WEBrick
    => Rails 2.3.5 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
    /home/siya/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:119:Warning: Gem::Dependency#version_requirements is deprecated and will be removed on or after August 2010.  Use #requirement
    /home/siya/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:589:in `real_connect': Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) (Mysql::Error)
        from /home/siya/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:589:in`connect'

This issue occur's when I restart my application. In fact yesterday it was running fine. But today I tried a lot and searched the web, but could not get success.

After googling, I got one command to update the system ie `sudo gem update --system`

Now new error occurs:

```
/home/siya/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:55: uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Mutex (NameError)
    from /home/siya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p330/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some-time, In resolving such type of issues. We again raise any other conflict.

> So best part is that,just take the
>   bakcup of application folder and
>   public folder. Re-install the whole
>   rails and ruby.

Because after investing whole day to resolve this issue. I followed this procedure. Please do not waste time.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade rails to the latest version (2.3.5 is fairly old).

```
gem install rails --version 2.3.11
```

You will also need to update your dependencies in your environment.rb, to set RAILS_GEM_VERSION to 2.3.11

```
Run rake rails:update
```

Test!  Rails upgrades seem to rarely be seamless.  You do have an extensive suite of unit tests, don't you... :)

Comment: I am not getting the perfect command for this. Please help me for this.

Comment: By following your way, System fall in New Error.=> Rails 2.3.11 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
config.load_paths is deprecated and removed in Rails 3, please use autoload_paths instead
config.load_paths= is deprecated and removed in Rails 3, please use autoload_paths= instead
NOTE: SourceIndex.new(hash) is deprecated; From /home/siya/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:100:in `new'.
/home/siya/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330/gems/activerecord-2.3.11

Comment: That's just a deprecation warning that it will be deprecated and removed in Rails 3.  You're using Rails 2.3.11, so it should still be there so far.  If you want to clear that up anyway, in your application.rb, change config.load_paths to config.autoload_paths.

Comment: Actually I cnt update Rails because I have to run Redmine over that using rvm 1.8.7. But Now this issue arises while running server command. undefined local variable or method `version_requirements' for #<Rails::GemDependency:0xb7375098> (NameError)

Comment: Rails 2.3.11 will still run on ruby 1.8.7, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: See Otto's response at http://www.redmine.org/issues/7516 for a solution.  It sounds like this is also resolved in RedMine if you update to the latest version of RedMine as well, due to be released in a month or so.

Comment: Simply, I just delete all the files and re-install the whole application. Now it is running. Thanks FOr you cooperation.